# Expo Project Does not start on Emulator

Tags: android-emulator, react-native, expo

Following the [documentation](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/workflow/android-studio-emulator/), I did install `expo-cli` and `android-studio` on Windows10 64bit. created an emulator with Google API 27 android Oreo 8.1.
`ANDROID_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME` are in the system varibales with their bins in thepath

- `expo init awesomeProject` chose experimental with native modules and tabbed theme.
- `cd awesomeProject` and both `yarn start` and `expo start` will start the `Expo Developer Tools` on `localhost:19002` with `Metro Bundler on port 19001`.
  the created Android Emulator is also open and running
- either pressing `a` on the command line or `run on android device/emulator` in DevTools **does nothing with no error.** no project opens on the emulator
- Devtools shows a toast `success simulator ready`, and terminal prints `opening on Android device`
- closing the emulator shows expected errors that there is no device.

What is wrong with my env setup?